# Safari extension message from background to popup not received

Tags: google-chrome-extension, messaging, safari-extension

I have a working v3 manifest chrome extension which I'm porting to Safari, but I'm encountering a problem when the background script sends a message to the popup: the popup doesn't receive it, and no exception is thrown at the (background) sender.

On popup initialisation, the popup declares its incoming message handler then notifies the background script that it is open via a call to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. After the background script has sent a message in reply and returned from its handler, it later uses the same function to send data to the popup:

```
try
{
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage( null, myMsg, null );
}
catch( err )
{
  console.log("error");
  console.log( err );
}
```

While that first send using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from the popup to the background succeeds (the popup receives the expected response message), the popup does not receive the subsequent message from the background - on Safari, that is; it does on Chrome. No exception is thrown in the above code.

To ensure that there is no race condition between the message from popup to the background and the message from background to popup, I've tried inserting a timeout of several seconds before sending the latter message; the popup remains open in the meantime.

Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: It's a bug in Safari, it doesn't correctly implement broadcasting of sendMessage. The workaround would be to reverse the direction of communication (let the popup start it). You can also use the native service worker messaging instead via `navigator.serviceWorker`, see web examples.

Comment: Thanks. The first of those workarounds will work for me.